# I get a TypeError *.a.* using webpack

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I get the following error: "TypeError: glm__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.vec3 is not a function" using webpack importing any npm package (the example is 'glm') on firefox.

main.js is:

```
    import glm from "glm";
    alert(glm.vec3(1, 2, 3));
```

package.json are:

```
{
        "name": "webpacktest",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "private": "true",
        "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
        "keywords": [],
        "author": "",
        "license": "ISC",
        "description": "",
        "dependencies": {
        "glm": "^1.0.0"
    },
        "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "^4.16.3",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    <script src="dist/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</html>
```

the file system is

- webpackettest

  - dist

    - main.js
  - node_modules

    - ...
  - src

    - index.js
  - index.html
  - package.json
  - package-lock.json

I followed the "getting started" guide of webpack with no success.

edited: main.js file, it does not have an "a" attribute, still get the exact same error

Comment: Could you create a reproducible example ? Because to me, `glm` doesn't have a `a` property.

Comment: I get the same error with that "a" property with any npm package. I have a larger project with the same error.

Comment: edited the main.js, it does not have an "a" attribute, still get the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, the problem was that I was using the wrong npm package. It should be "glm-js" not "glm".

By the way the correct way to import a package from webpack is:

```
import * as glm from 'glm-js';
```

instead of:

```
import glm from 'glm-js';
```